# Eclipse plugin development new eclipse window not opening on run via right click and select eclipse application

Tags: java

**Getting below error while trying to run Plugin project from eclipse. By Right click on project and run as eclipse project
    Error in logs :**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.6.0.I20160606-1100
java.version=1.8.0_131
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide
Command-line arguments:  -product org.eclipse.sdk.ide -data /home/xvervik/workspace/master/../runtime-EclipseApplication -dev file:/home/xvervik/workspace/master/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/Eclipse Application/dev.properties -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.ui 4 4 2017-10-30 10:07:23.294
!MESSAGE could not create trigger point advisor
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.ui.activities.WorkbenchTriggerPointAdvisor cannot be found by com.ericsson.eecs.shared.branding_2.0.0.201607211826
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:448)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:361)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:353)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.loadClass(EquinoxBundle.java:564)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.registry.osgi.RegistryStrategyOSGI.createExecutableExtension(RegistryStrategyOSGI.java:174)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:830)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$4.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.stop(BundleContextImpl.java:823)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.stopWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:946)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:314)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.decStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1580)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stopWorker(SystemModule.java:253)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule.stopWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStop(Module.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.stop(Module.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.SystemModule.stop(SystemModule.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$SystemBundle$EquinoxSystemModule$1.run(EquinoxBundle.java:165)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Job found still running after platform shutdown.  Jobs should be canceled by the plugin that scheduled them during shutdown: org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.wizards.MarketplaceDropAdapter$1
```

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build all the project. Your problem will be resolved.